# Import library is not resolved

Tags: java, jar, mp4, executable-jar, mp4parser

I have tried to compile a java program, [shorten.java](https://mp4parser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/ShortenExample.java) from mp4parser site. But my jar file is unable to resolve the required import shown below.
This program needs to import library from iso mp4parser  as mentioned below.  **In short I need jar file for shorten.java   file  to resolve these import.**

```
import com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile;
import com.coremedia.iso.boxes.TimeToSampleBox;
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.Movie;
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.Track;
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.builder.DefaultMp4Builder;
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator;
import com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.CroppedTrack;
```

I have downloaded the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fisoparser) from the mp4parser site to create the jar file for these library.

In below image **java->com->coremedia->iso**   and   **java->com->coremedia->iso->boxes**   having required java program

and **java->com->googlecode->mp4parser->authoring**  etc.  having other needed  java program for   these import

**I have created the jar by following command-**

```
cd  java           // moved in java folder

jar cfv mp4parser.jar   *
```

**now add these jar to my shorten.java program.
But I am getting error that  import is not resolved.**

****Do anybody can tell me where I am doing mistake ???****

Here is the directory where java codes for these imports are available.

[image: directory structure for included java code]

Comment: jars are imported into your project/module as a separate step in your IDE. They are not be picked up automagically based on which directory you add them to. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Hi Peter,

I am using Eclipse.
I have created the jar by command prompt and then attach jar from build path.
I am sure I am attaching correctly because I have attached jar files before with other program

Comment: If you are attaching jars you built in a manner which worked correctly before then its likely you have built the jars incorrectly.  When you examine the `jar` does it have `.class` files or `.java` files?

Comment: how to check does my jar have .class or .java file???

Comment: You can unpack it or list it with `jar -tv` , but I thought eclipse has a viewer for jars.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Got some other work.
I have seen my jar, it is having .java files  only.
Do I need require .class files for my purpose.

Comment: It has to contain the compiled .class files. You can add the .java files but these will be ignored.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to this:

- Create a quickstart java project with maven;
- Add the dependencies that you want;
- Put the java class in src/main/java
- `mvn clean install`

If it don't work, try some IDE, like eclipse. Open the project and try to fix the imports... It's always possible that some lib has changed, and maybe they change the name of the package.

Comment: Hi caarlos,
can you pls tell me little bit more how to do this with eclipse??
I have checked that name is not changed.

Comment: you know how to use eclipse? and maven? explain a little more your problem and I'll try to help you.

Comment: My problem is that I have the source code for the required libraries in mentioned   import.
Then I have created the jar from  this source code 
But its giving compilation error that import is not resolved

Comment: as I said, maybe the libraries changed... maybe the import used in your file was deprecated, and now you will have to use another one.. is just a guess.. but, generally, that's the problem..

Comment: source code for these imported libraries are    from   http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fisoparser

Comment: Actually both the code  and    source code from where I am creating jar file,   both are latest.
So I dont think its deprecated

Comment: do you have maven installed? if yes, go to the directory of the project and run `mvn clean install eclipse:eclipse`. It should download all the required libraries automatically and configure you eclipse to use it. The jar will be generated in your local repo (usually `YOUR_USER_HOME/.m2/repository`